# React com Material-UI: Trocar cores dos componentes

Tags: javascript, react, material-design

Estou com uma dúvida sobre os `buttons` (creio que irá sanar os demais componentes também). Existe a propriedade `color`, por padrão posso utilizar `primary`ou `secondary`, ambas vem junto com o material.
Mas e se eu quiser um botão de fundo verde, como faria isso? Existe a possibilidade de criar uma nova propriedade `color` chamada `third`por exemplo e pintar o fundo do botão de verde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Tente:**

Primeiro, dê uma olhada neste exemplo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bd92xq

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// Crie seu próprio tema:
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#757ce8',
      main: '#3f50b5',
      dark: '#002884',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#ff7961',
      main: '#f44336',
      dark: '#ba000d',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
    third: {
      light: '#5fba7d',
      main: '#f44336',
      dark: '#ba000d',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
{/*Lembre de importar o botão*/}
      <Button
     variant="raised"
     color="third" {/*Ou: color={theme.palette.third}*/}
   </Button>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

> **Em seguida, você pode ler alguns materiais:**

- [Customization-color/](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/)
- [Alterar cores secundárias e primárias na interface do usuário(en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535551/change-secondary-and-primary-colors-in-materual-ui)
- [Como adicionar várias cores da paleta Material UI (en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069724/how-to-add-multiple-material-ui-palette-colors)

Comment: Amigo, a cor para `primary` e `secondary` mudam, mas para `third`ainda fica "em branco"

Comment: Você viu este exemplo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bd92xq ?

Comment: Taffarel, desculpe a demora. Sim... eu vi o exemplo, inclusive consegui fazer. Não sei se você percebeu, mas se eu troco o `variant` do botão ele não funciona... isso é contornável? Manter os `variants` padrões tem como?

Comment: Realmente, eu vi. Não sei como resolver isso. Vamos tentar.